# Outbound 500 Inbound 500 // Cancel inbound flight

Tags: canada

So I'm looking to buy a ticket for my gf to come to Canada and she'd have to get a back home ticket. We would eventually get her papers in order to allow her to stay but then we'd have to cancel the inbound ticket.

I'm not a big fan of losing all the money.

Do you have any advice on how to get the best deal on this?

I have with Lufthansa a couple of options:

~500 outbound and 500 inbound - loose all money

~500 outbound and 900 inbound (in case of cancelation I lose 70 Eur + fare difference)

What would that fare difference mean anyways?

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: 'eventually get her papers in order'? You should get her papers in order first, then you won't need a return ticket. You seem to have this back-to-front.

Comment: That wasn't the question and it's not debatable. If you can answer my question please do so.

Comment: You need to fix the question first, @Lion. As it stands it's not suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

Fare difference means that if you rebook the ticket you have to pay for the difference in fare.  So if you buy a $900 ticket, cancel the reservation, and then use it for a $1200 flight, you'd have to pay $300 for the fare difference in addition to the change fee and other fees and taxes.

This doesn't apply if the fare is refunded to you, of course.

Comment: Its worth noting that if the two legs (out and return) are part of the same ticket, and you cancel the return, then the out flight will typically be reticketed as a single and you would pay the fare difference between what you paid for it as part of a return and what you would have paid for it as a single.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to phoogs excellent answer, there is a gotcha when it comes to return tickets.

If you buy your outbound and return flights as part of the same ticket, so a return ticket, and you cancel either portion of the ticket, the other portion will often be re-ticketed as a single and the appropriate fare difference will be applied.

So, if you paid $500 for the outbound and $900 for the return as part of the same ticket, and you cancelled the $900 return portion, then the airline will look to see what price the $500 outbound portion should have been as a single.

If the single for the same portion was being sold for $1000, then you would get back the following:

```
500 + 900 = 1400 (this is the total you paid)

1400 - 1000 = 400 (this is the re-ticketing of the outbound)

400 - 70 = 330 (this is the residual value)
```

So in my above example, you would get back ***$330*** (perhaps a bit more if airport taxes and fees are considered separately).

Note that the figures I use are an example - you would need to speak to the airline to see just what the actual figures might be.

Comment: Their one way are like 1300 comparing to 500 so I'd get screwed out of most money.

Comment: Doesn't sound great but thanks for all the replies guys

Comment: Do you know if Air Canada's policy is similar or I might have better luck?